# How to get spyder v3.0.0 with conda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, conda

it seems that spyder IDE v3.0.0 is out (see https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases), and it could be installed in Anaconda package.

Trying to upgrade it with:

```
conda update qt pyqt
conda install spyder
```

I cannot get this version v3 as claimed.

Is there anyone who managed to get it ?

Thanks!

Comment: (*Spyder developer here*) I'm sorry it hasn't been updated yet. It should be in conda at most tomorrow :-)

Comment: Great ! No rush !
Thanks a lot for your answer !